# Adding properties to an object dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying to create objects at runtime. We have .net framework provided classes like DynamicObject and ExpandoObject. Is it possible to create a dynamic object like this

```
dynamic obj = new expandoObject();
obj["propName1"] = "name"; //string type
obj["propName2"] = 24; //int type
```

I dont know the property names until runtime. Is it possible to do this way?

Comment: Isn't a dictionary enough?

Comment: If you don't know the property names until runtime, how do you intend to read the values afterwards? As @BlackBear says, why can't you use a dictionary?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420427/add-property-to-poco-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, two things.

First, yes, you *can* stuff values into the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object using "property names" contained in strings, because it implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can do it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
    dict["propName1"] = "test";
    dict["propName2"] = 24;

    Debug.WriteLine("propName1=" + (object)obj.propName1);
    Debug.WriteLine("propName2=" + (object)obj.propName2);
}
```

Notice how I use the property syntax to retrieve the values there. Unfortunately, `dynamic` is like a virus and propagates, and `Debug.WriteLine` is none too happy about `dynamic` values, so I had to cast to `object` there.

However, and this is the second thing, if you don't know the property names until runtime, those last two lines there won't appear anywhere in your program. The only way to retrieve the values is again to cast it to a dictionary.

So you're better off just using a dictionary to begin with:

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    obj["propName1"] = "name";
    obj["propName2"] = 24;

    Debug.WriteLine("propName1=" + obj["propName1"]);
    Debug.WriteLine("propName2=" + obj["propName2"]);
}
```